# make Blast search take longer time

Tags: database, search, cloud, blast

i am referring to this link : http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK52637/ , to try blast search on the single machine. I had dl the blast app and refseq_rna blast database from the NCBI website. The blast search take only few seconds to get the result. I want to ask if there any way that can make the blast search take more time to search for a matching sequence on a blast database ?

Answer (score 0):

BLAST is a heuristic, it's designed to be really fast. Also some of the results on the NCBI interface are precomputed. Why you would want this process to take longer I can't imagine, but you could try running a Smith-Waterman alignment algorithm, this will find truly optimum matches and will take a massively longer time than BLAST on a large database.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could tell us why you want to slow it down!?

But for what it's worth, reduce the word size using the -W option.